# Is it possible to display dict.values() under the wx.ComboBox but transmit dict.keys() to Bind event?

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working on a GUI based on wxpython and have the following question regarding wx.Combobox feature:

Is it possible to display dict.values() in the drop down list and select one of the displayed item but in Bind event send dict.key for this item somehow? I want to present possible options for selection in a user friendly way - example is below.

I think it should be possible with the dictionary but don't know how to realize that.

I'm parsing all Sections from INI file with configparser to a list:

```
sections= ['123ABC456','123DEF456','123GHI456','123JKL456','123MNO456']
```

and assign it to Combobox:

```
self.combo_sections = wx.ComboBox(panel, choices=sections)
self.combo_sections.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_combo_sections)

self.on_combo_sections function is parsing section's options.
```

What i need is to convert list items to a readable format:

```
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO']
```

And display these values under combobox drop down list. Since initial Section's values are essential for further work - based on section name, configparser gets section's options, how can i send original values instead of formatted ones but still display formatted ones under the drop down?

Thanks in advance for any inputs!

Comment: The sections in the `ini` file will be unique, that will not necessarily be so, if you start using only a part of the name. Be sure that this doesn't trip you up.

Answer (score 1):

`wxComboBox` supports associating the so called "client data" with each of its items, so you can use this and store the sections value as this client data, then you will be able to get them back whenever you have an index of combobox item.

Alternatively, just keep your own array in combobox items order and store the sections in it -- this is more or less how "client data" is implemented internally anyhow.

The main advantage of using built-in client data support is that it is kept in sync even if the items are added/inserted/deleted to/from the control, but if your combobox doesn't change after creation, using your own data structure should be simpler.